# NanoPi 2 Fire doesn't boot OS image

Tags: boot, u-boot, buildroot, nanopi

After building output by buildroot , I found 4 files in image dir :
u-boot.bin
uImage
rootfs.tar.gz and rootfs.tar.

I extracted it with sdfuse nanopi2 and master , of course i delete zImage from prebuilt dir and power on board with HDMI connect but screen show only color horizontal bars and blue LED on board is light continuously.

When i use win32diskimager to extract NanoPi2 Debian image , it works and boots Debian OS.

I use UART and following messages show:

```
BOARD= [NanoPi 2 Fire]
LCD = N/A (-1)
MMC: NXP DWMMC: 0, NXP DWMMC: 1, NXP DWMMC: 2
In: serial
Out: serial
Err: serial
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
HDMI: display.0, preset 0 (1280 * 720)
HDMI: PHY Ready!!!
Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
can't find bmp at 0x47000000 (type:0xffff), fb:0x46000000...
LOGO: DRAW FB=0x46000000, X=1280, Y= 720, Bpp=32
Hit any key to stop autoboot: 0 
Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
Failed to mount ext2 filesystem...
** Unrecognized filesystem type **
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

Answer (score 0):

The official Buildroot does not have a configuration for the NanoPi 2 Fire, so your question does not give enough details to explain what the problem is.

But basically, if all you got as a build output is u-boot.bin, uImage and rootfs.tar(.gz), then your Buildroot configuration has not generated a ready-to-use SD card image. So you would have to format the SD card properly, and copy the right files at the right location.

Comment: Thanks,how I can make Buildroot to generate SD card image??

Comment: *"how I can make Buildroot to generate SD card image?"* -- Some people have used [genimage](https://github.com/vivien/genimage/blob/master/README) in a post-build script.  But it would be prudent to first test what you have already built with a hand-crafted SDcard.